# Scroll to Datagridview selected Row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, search, datagridview, row

I've done quite a bit of searching for this answer but none have been able to help me. I've attempted to use or even see if `.Focus()`was applicable since other websites suggested it, but it is not. I would just like the `DataGridView`,  HistoryData.

to jump to the selected row. It of course does so but it will not scroll to it when enough items fill the grid. Could there be a parameter i'm missing on the grid?

Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub HistorySearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HistorySearch.TextChanged
    Try
        If HistorySearch.Text.ToString <> "" Then
            For Each HistoryRow As DataGridViewRow In HistoryData.Rows
                HistoryData.ClearSelection()
                For Each HistoryCell As DataGridViewCell In HistoryRow.Cells

                    If HistoryCell.Value.ToString.StartsWith(HistorySearch.Text.ToString) Then
                        HistoryRow.Selected = True
                        Dim i As Integer = HistoryData.CurrentRow.Index()

                    Else
                        HistoryRow.Selected = False
                    End If
                    If HistoryCell.Value.ToString.Contains(HistorySearch.Text.ToString) Then
                        HistoryRow.Selected = True
                        Dim i As Integer = HistoryData.CurrentRow.Index()
                        Return
                    Else
                        HistoryRow.Selected = False
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You can scroll to specific row in `DataGridView` using either of these options:

**CurrentCell**

If you set the [`CurrentCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of `DataGridView` it selects the specified cell and scrolls to make the cell visible.

For example to select the last row and scroll to it:

```vb
'use suitable index, 10 is just for example
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows(10).Cells(0)
```

**FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex**

You can also set [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to scroll to a specific row, but it doesn't select the row:

For example to only scroll to the 10th row:

```vb
'use suitable index, 10 is just for example
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 10
```

Comment: About the solution #1, what if Cells(0) is not visible? It raises an exception, I need to loop over cells and check the first with visible = true